# Cannot install requirements file after reinstalling python 3.7.3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I had python 3.7 (32-bit) installed on my system, but couldn't run TensorFlow on it, so I made a requirements file of all the packages and uninstalled python. After installing python 3.7.3 (64-bit) I ran,

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

with the requirements.txt file in the same directory but I get this error:

```
Invalid requirement: 'pip install'
```

This is how the requirements.txt file looks like in case of syntax error.

```
kiwisolver==1.0.1
lxml==4.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.0.2
mglearn==0.1.7
mistune==0.8.4
nbconvert==5.4.0
nbformat==4.4.0
nose==1.3.7
notebook==5.7.4
numpy==1.16.0
pandas==0.24.1
```

What am I doing wrong? I searched for it and one post told me that maybe the syntax of requirements.txt is wrong but I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: Looks like you've run `pip install 'pip install'` or your `requirements.txt` contains `pip install`.

Comment: I checked for that but there are no 'pip install' in the requirements file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Command Prompt and for a version of Python 3.7.3:-

> `py -3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Step 2:-

> `py -3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

In macOS and for a version of Python 3.7.3:-

> `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`

Step 2:-

> `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`